# Input box width uneven on mobile

Tags: html, css, input, width

I am trying to make a paper calculator, it works fine, However there is a design problem.

The input boxes are correctly displayed on pc screen, even in responsive option (where you can choose screen size) but on the actual phones, the input boxes don't have equal widths.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div id = "case_one"  class="calcoptions sizemod">

<h5>1. To find the weight (in <b>Kilograms</b>) of a ream containing 500 sheets of a given size in <b>inches</b> and <b>Gram-Weight.</b></h5> 
<br>    

Length: <input type="number" step="0.01" name="length_in" id="txt_weight" placeholder="Length(inch)" style = "width:auto;" min="0" onkeyup="calculateWeightInInches();">
<br><br>

Width: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" style = "width:auto;" step="0.01" name="width_in" id="txt_width" placeholder="Width(inch)" min="0" max='300' onkeyup="calculateWeightInInches();">
<br><br>

GSM: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" style = "width:auto;" min="5" max="800" step="0.01" name="length_in" id="txt_GSM" placeholder="GSM" onkeyup="calculateWeightInInches();">
<br><br>

Weight: <input type="number" style = "width:auto;" step = "0.01" name="Weight_Kg" id = "txt_Result" readonly="readonly">
<br><br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {


text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}

input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .sizemod {    
    display: none;
     

  }
}

@media (min-width: 858px) {
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 780px) {
    html {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 702px) {
    html {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 724px) {
    html {
        font-size: 9px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 623px) {
    html {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}

select {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
        /*font-style: italic;*/ 
    }
    select#fixed {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

textarea {
    width: 20px;
};

input[type="number"] {
    width: 20px;
};
```

On PC:
[image: On PC boxes are okay]

On actual Mobile:
[image: tested on multiple devices]

P.S. The style = width:auto; tag was added just now, didn't work.

Comment: You are totally wrong, if you expect `width:auto` would achieve what you want here. You want them all to be the same width - then you will have to _specify_ that width somewhere.

Comment: I would suggest to use a relative width like 80% for the input fields. That way you can make it dependent of the container-div 'case_one' which you can adjust in the media querie. Further add a max-width in pixel to limit the relative width to a size of your liking.
`input {width:80%; max-width:200px;}`

also not sure how you want to addres  the fields, but if you do by name pay attention that you named the first and the third field alike: length_in

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you should keep in mind, is that they are two different browsers, so they can act differently. I'd also recommend using a set width, rather than auto. Setting a width to auto essentially tells the browser to do as it wants, which it is in your case.

Hope this helps!